# Check if a string contains executable code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an Android app that runs my code(which is a JS bundle) in a hidden webview. I make API calls through native code using a JS interface. The response is sent back to a function through the evaluetJavascript method of the webview. The concern here is somehow a malicious response is received which might execute arbitrary JS in my webview. I am base-64 encoding the result before calling the evaluateJavascript and once it reaches the JS, I just decode it and parse the JSON and then it's just a string value which gets used further.

I have 2 questions:

(1) Since I am not using eval() anywhere in my JS code, is my understanding correct that even if a code gets through, it won't ever execute?

(2) I have been asked to still validate the data. Is there any way to detect if a given string contains executable JS code? I thought of looking for characters like ;"'() etc. but have concerns that my data may contain parentheses and that a stringified JSON will have quotes anyways. I am worried about false positives. What will be a better approach for this?

Comment: Could you show us an example string containing this "executable code"?

Comment: @Jack Any executable JS code, like "window.alert('test')" for example.

Comment: That would probably be very complicated (maybe there is a library for that), and I don't think there is fully reliable way to check. The most reliable should be to parse it with JSON parser

Comment: @Slai I am already using JSON.parse on the string I receive. Will this mitigate the chances of a malicious code passing through?

Comment: `JSON.parse` does not execute any code, and would not work if the string contains anything other than "objects, arrays, numbers, strings, booleans, and null" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: @Slai Would any injection be possible by maybe a value of any of the keys in JSON containing code? Since I am not using eval anywhere, it shouldn't happen right?

Comment: yes, as long as eval() or similar (or inserting the values as HTML) is not used, it's fully safe

Comment: You could pass the data through a try catch. In the try you would you eval() the data. It if fails then you know the data doesn't contain any executable. Well nothing that would execute successfully.

Comment: @MokkyMiah Won't that actually run the code? That's what I am trying to prevent.